# how to enter PIN number at command ??? I have tried to following to no success

Tags: at-command, modem, 3g, sim-toolkit

at+stgi=23 
+STGI:23,2,8,1,0,0,28,"0045006E007400650072002000500049004E0020006E006F002E003A 
OK
how to enter PIN in at command line?

Answer (score 5):

Use `AT+CPIN?` to see which PIN is requested, if any, and `AT+CPIN="1234"` to enter PIN 1234.

([Source](http://terzo.acmesystems.it/download/datasheets/M95_ATC_V1.1.pdf) + [standard](http://www.3gpp.org/ftp/Specs/html-info/27007.htm))

Comment: i have fund solution at+stgi=23,"PIN"